# Why does a PHP script use different amounts of memory on two servers?

Tags: php

I have a fairly large webapp that I run on a Media Temple server. We have recently decided to move it to the Rackspace cloud. When I run `get_memory_usage`, I'm using about 4mb of RAM more, per page load. So I guess I have a couple questions.

1. Does it matter?
2. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. It can, if the memory limit isn't raised appropriately as well.
2. Additional extensions, or 32-bit versus 64-bit binaries/pointers.

Comment: There is plenty of room between the memory limit and memory usage, and you're right, It's 64bit vs 32bit.

Answer (score 2):

Your Rackspace Cloud server is probably 64bit which will generally take up more memory.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely that your PHP configurations are different on both servers.  The php configurations register_globals and register_long_arrays will use a little bit more memory because all Get/Post/Cookie are duplicated.  Also some PHP modules will use more memory such as "Hardned-PHP" which isn't installed on all systems.